# How to access to a Resource.resx from ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to access a resource-file from ASP.NET page.
I have a folder named "Resources" containing the file "WebResources.resx" on the same level as the page.
The name of the public class in the generated WebResources.Designer.cs is also "WebResources"
My page's name is "formulargenerator.aspx".
Access from code-behind works perfectly. I can access in 2 ways:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(WebResources));
string val = rm.GetString("Key");
```

And

```
string val = WebResources.Key;
```

But how can I access from page directly if I don't like to rename the Resource-file?
I have tried to use the folder App_LocalResources - no access.
Only if the resource-file is named like the page does it work.
How is the syntax to access a ressource? The code below doesn't work. Must/Can I import a namespace?

```
<asp:Label Text="<%$Resources: WebResources, Key%>" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take look at [ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx). Local resources are specific to a concrete aspx page and use a different naming convention than global application resources. The resource tag you are using is more-likely to work if using global resources.

Comment: I have read it but I can not use a App_Global- or App_LocalResources. If I rename the resx-file to the same like the aspx it works in Web but not in code-behind the generated class is named as the page but dot is replaced by underscore. (page_aspx). If nothing helps then all controls will get an ID and I will set the values in onLoad().

Comment: Are you saying you cannot access the resources in the code-behind when they are added to the App_GlobalResources? Usually, if you use Visual Studio to add the class to the App_GlobalResources, you get the following code generated: `namespace Resourecs; internal class MyResources { /* .. some resouce stuff and properties */ }`. You can access them by using `Resources.MyResources.Key`. MyResources would be the name of the resource file.

Comment: I don't like to use App_GlobalResources because many developers develop some modules for our web-application. They will be installed separately. If possible without any interaction with other modules or the web app itself. I hoped, I could deploy a single folder and this is it.

Comment: Maybe then a local resource file is a better-suited solution for your case. If you want a better way of getting the resource values in the code-behind, then you might consider writing a simple resource provider class that will get the resource automatically.

Comment: I think the easiest way for me is to give all controls an ID. I hoped I could set a namespace or something other to the ASPX-file so it would access a file like xyz.resx. I dind't know how difficulty this is.