# Unable to access resources in .net web project

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, resources

How do I access resources in a .Net Web Project. I created a web project and then in App_LocalResources folder added a resx file "AstroWap.resx". Now how do I access values from that. The property My.Resources itself is not available.

Answer (score 0):

To create an access properties - right click your solution, select properties then click the link to create a resource file. You should see a excel type grid. Type your key value pairs in there.

To access it should be

```
<Namespace>.Properties.Resources.<ResourceName>
```

The issue is probably how you have added the resource. It might have circumvented the auto generated code which gives you the above syntax

You can check if it has added the auto gen code by looking in your web project under properties -> resources.resx -> resource.cs.designer. The designer file is the autogenerated file and you can see the access code for the underlying resx file. This assumes you have used the default resx file as above. See image for example in solution explorer

[image]

In addition this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451756/how-to-access-to-a-resource-resx-from-asp-net-page) does give more options for accessing resx files if you have some project constraints. I appreciate not everyone can do the above due to team work practices etc.. It's just what I do. And it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Good reference reading to use resource files [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use following code for it:

```
<%=GetLocalResourceObject("labelname")%>
```

in aspx page.
If your page name is Test.aspx then your resource file must have name as Test.aspx.resx, otherwise you can not access the resource file value.